# Faculty member whose research is the same as their PhD thesis

Tags: publications

In mathematics, suppose we have a PhD who worked on a very spefic topic X during their PhD thesis. When they become a postdoc, they'll likely work on the same thing or related subjects. However, let's say after they have become a faculty member since quite some while ago, let's say more than a decade after finishing their PhD, and they have still been publishing papers on X only.

My question is: will this be looked down upon? Will this cause trouble in future promotion?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community No, the questions are clear and it is easy to tell what OP is asking.

Comment: It depends.  One of the 2011 Nobel Prize in Physics winners (I forget which one) told me a few years ago that he started working on the expansion of the universe at the start of his PhD.  He had not worked on anything else since.  That strategy will not be good for most academics.

Comment: @Oliver882 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369272/resolving-community-user-and-share-feedback-issues-in-review-queues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is too little information to judge. If they have been productive and their publication record shows progress in that narrow field and provides insight to others then no. But if it is a dead-end niche (hard to judge), then perhaps (but not a definite yes).

And, if they have been at it for a decade or more then they are probably a tenured associate professor (US system), so it doesn't matter a lot to them.

Moreover, if they were in at the beginning of a substantive development in the field, then it would be entirely natural to keep following those threads.

Note that if they keep publishing papers in X, then the reviewers are continuously judging that their work is fine, assuming reputable journals.

Promotion, say to Full Professor is hard to judge, since it is done by peers who form their own judgements. The individual needs to make their own case as is true for everyone. Not publishing would likely prejudice the case.

If you want to work in that area, then they are probably just the right person to work with as they likely have a lot of insight that they can pass along.

But everyone gets to judge whether they look up or down on others and it is often for the wrong reasons.

When I was a doctoral student I had a friend who was an (early career) associate professor in that math department. He predicted he would never make Full, since the standards were so high. Happily, he was wrong and retired as a Full Professor.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it depends on the merits of that research.  There is nothing inherently wrong with pursuing the same line of research as in your PhD, so long as that leads to fruitful research discoveries later on.  Doing so could just be a sign that you picked a great PhD topic.